# I want to remove object from array based on object id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter an object based on the id that I want to remove from the array I am using the filter to remove it but it not working properly my task is I need to remove only that object whose id will match and I will send the remaining data as it is in the payload

```
  const deleteChartData = (id) => {
    monitoringResult?.monitoringResults?.opCharts?.filter(
      (col) => col.id !== id
    );
    setMonitoringResult({ ...monitoringResult, monitoringResult });
    setTimeout(() => {
      formikForm.handleSubmit();
    }, 0);
  };
```

Comment: You are not using the result if your `filter`. Ie, filter does nit modify the existing array but returns a new array cases on your filter condition. and what do you expect `{ ...monitoringResult, monitoringResult }` to do?

Comment: See https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#

Answer (score 0):

you're not saving filtered results. Filter doesn't change orignal array, it returns a new array.

```
const result = monitoringResult?.monitoringResults?.opCharts?.filter(
  (col) => col.id !== id
);
// result will have all objects except the object of id passed to deleteChartData.
```

Comment: but it will create a new key in my I case I need to return data in the same array key name

Comment: you can add this result data in that specific key of your nested object

Comment: Also, you need to clone your original object (create a new object) to update your state because React requires state to be immutable

Answer (score 0):

Find the index you want to remove, then remove it from a shallow copy and then set that as your new data

```
const deleteChartData = (id) => {

    const tmpCopy = { ...monitoringResult?.monitoringResults?.opCharts };
    const indexToRemove = tmpCopy.findIndex(
      (col) => col.id !== id
    );

    if (indexToRemove >= 0) {
        tmpCopy.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
    
    setMonitoringResult({ ...tmpCopy });
  };
```